# In python, numpy.linalg.eigh function gives segmentation fault.

Tags: python, numpy

I am running a python code to find out eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a covariance matrix on a cluster. The following line gives me segmentation fault error:

`eigenVals, eigenVectors = numpy.linalg.eigh(covMat)`

where covMat is a

> covariance matrix of dimension (50000,50000)

When the same code i run on my laptop with dimension (1000,1000) it gives me correct results without any segmentation fault.

Is this the error due to the higher dimension of covMat ?

I have checked versions of numpy library and python. They are similar to the version i have installed on my laptop. 
How can i solve this issue?  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't know if it is of any help but have you looked at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/613?

Comment: No, actually if it gives error it should give with numpy.linalg.eig() also. It gives results without any error. But due to the round off part numpy.linalg.eig() function gives complex eigenvalues. I studied that we don't face this problem of complex number with numpy.linalg.eigh(). Both uses almost same laplack algorithm.